# Google Sheets v4 .NET batch get A1 notation for first row then all rows starting from another row

Tags: google-sheets, range, array-formulas, google-sheets-formula, notation

Brand new to Google Sheets API and A1 notation syntax.

I want to make a batch get to get the first row alone, and then all rows after a specified row.

I'm pretty sure `'Sheetname'!1:1` will get me the first row alone (right?), but what's the A1 notation for "Row 7 and any rows after row 7"?

Keep in mind I am using the .NET Google Sheets v4 API, so I am doing something like:

```cs
SpreadsheetsResource.ValuesResource.BatchGetRequest request = service.Spreadsheets.Values.BatchGet(MY_SPREADSHEET_ID);

request.DateTimeRenderOption = SpreadsheetsResource.ValuesResource.BatchGetRequest.DateTimeRenderOptionEnum.FORMATTEDSTRING;

request.Ranges = // what goes here?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that the way to do this is to specify the row and first column for the beginning of the range, and then a column that is beyond your known columns with no row specified to get all rows containing data after the row specified at the beginning of the range.

And for the .NET Sheets API, the way to specify multiple ranges is with a `List<string>`.

In my particular case, my columns end at `N`, so I know column `Z` is well beyond any data, so this would work to get me the first row, and then row 7 and all rows with data after row 7:

```
request.Ranges = new List<string>
{
    "Sheetname!A1:Z1",
    "Sheetname!A7:Z"
};
```

Answer (score 1):

this should do the trick:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({Sheetname!1:1; INDIRECT("Sheetname!7:"&MAX(ROW(A1:A)))})
```

[image: 0]

or perhaps:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({Sheetname!1:1; Sheetname!7:999999})
```

Comment: I see that it works if you put that in the sheet itself, but Google Sheets API v4 for .NET is not liking that.  If I make my `BatchGetRequest` object and set the `Ranges` property of the request to a string like that, I get a `Google.GoogleApiException`: "Unable to parse ranges".

Comment: perhaps try it without stringy indirect thing with huge row number as end range

Comment: Nope, same error.  And I also tried losing the `ARRAYFORMULA` part and just did `request.Ranges = "'Sheetname'!1:1; 'Sheetname'!7:999999";` and that also gave the same error.